# C# WinForm hook Enter key in propertygrid textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, propertygrid

I have hooked the textbox in a propertygrid as following

```
private void SetupKeyDownHookForPropertyGrid(PropertyGrid targetGrid, bool shouldHook)
{
    foreach (Control control in targetGrid.Controls)
    {
        if (control.GetType().Name == "PropertyGridView")
        {
            foreach (Control realControl in control.Controls)
            {
                if (realControl.GetType().Name == "GridViewEdit")
                {
                    TextBox targetTextBox = realControl as TextBox;
                    // hookKeyDown is a callback function
                    targetTextBox.KeyDown += hookKeyDown;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can successfully hook any key that users press, except the Enter key(which will update the property for the selected object directly).

It seems that the KeyDown event is not dispatched to the textbox but handle by some top level controls of propertygrid.

Is there any solution to hook the Enter key press in textbox of a PropertyGrid?

Thank you!

Comment: And except Escape and F4.  You are playing a pretty dangerous game, when you think of hacking PropertyGrid like this then you've gone beyond the point where it is still useful and should consider creating your own edit Form class instead.  Technically you can still hook by overriding the form's ProcessCmdKey() method, use this.ActiveControl to detect that the focus is on the PropertyGrid.

Comment: I agree with you. This kind of hook is a dirty approach. I would like to create a custom form to handle such a situation. Thank you anyway.